# How to execute exit function in a python module?

Tags: python, module, atexit

I am writing a module in Python which runs some processes in background.I want them to be ended once the user exits the python interpreter.I have used the atexit module and registered my exit() function.However, I am still not able to kill the background processes because the function is not running.
My Module structure is this:

```
my_package:
       __init__.py
       function1.py
       function2.py
       exit.py
```

This is my exit.py function

```
from atexit import register


    def exit_formalities():
          ///Deleting temp directories and folders///


register(exit_formalities)
```

Comment: Don't use the name `exit`. There's already an existing builtin with that name. Try changing it and see what happens.

Comment: I have changed it to exit_fomalities() and registered it.Still no luck

Comment: Well, without any further information, nothing can be said. Please look at how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: looks like you are using `atexit`'s `register()` call properly. Clearly something is going wrong in your `exit_formalities()` call. You're gonna have to showcase the code in that function for us to spot where you might be going wrong.